# Implement Carrierwave_direct in Wicked Wizard Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have an app set up with a Wicked Wizard form to create a new post.
The last step allows users to upload pictures to their post.
For image processing I am using Carrierwave and Fog (because I'm hosting the site on heroku and I am using Amazon S3 for storage).
It's all working fine, but the upload to Amazon S3 is very slow.

Following Ryan Bates' Uploading to Amazon S3 railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3) I tried Carrierwave_Direct (https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct) to speed up the painfully slow upload to Amazon S3.

When doing this, however, I get an error:

```
NoMethodError in PostSteps#show

Showing    
/Users/petersonneveld/rails_projects/doamer/doamer2/app/views/property_steps/picture.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `direct_fog_url' for nil:NilClass
```

I really don't know what to do to solve this. Does anyone have advice? Thanks a bunch for your help!

In the last step of my wicked wizard form I have

```
# app/views/post_steps/picture.html.erb

<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader, url: wizard_path do |f| %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <h2>Let's post some pictures!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
          <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <%= f.label :image, "Upload image" %><br>
        <%= image_tag(@post.image_url(:thumb)).to_s if @post.image? %>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <%= f.label :remote_image_url, "or paste image URL" %>
        <%= f.text_field :remote_image_url, class: "form-control" %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <h4><%= f.check_box :remove_image %> 
        <span class="label label-danger">Remove image</span></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <%= f.button "Finish", class: "btn btn-primary", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Saving post..."} %>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And in my controller

```
# app/controllers/post_steps_controller.rb

class PostStepsController < ApplicationController
include Wicked::Wizard
steps :description, :picture

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  render_wizard
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @post.update_attributes(post_params)
  render_wizard @post
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(...)
end

def redirect_to_finish_wizard(options = nil)
  redirect_to @post, notice: "Thanks for submitting a post."
end
end
```

And my post controller create action

```
# app/controllers/post_controller.rb

def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to post_steps_path(:id => "description", :post_id => @post.id)
    else
      render :new
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: had to update the 'aws-sdk' gem!